# Export multiple query results to a single csv

Tags: sql, sql-server, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a query with one result, and export it to a csv instead of multiple like I have been doing. It seems so simple but I can't figure it out.

```
SELECT 
      database_name = DB_NAME(5)
    , log_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'LOG' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , row_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'ROWS' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
FROM sys.master_files WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE database_id =(5) 
GROUP BY database_id

SELECT * FROM emp select @@ROWCOUNT 

SELECT * FROM BADGE WHERE STATUS=1 select @@ROWCOUNT
activebadges 

SELECT * FROM dbo.EVENTS select @@ROWCOUNT 
eventstotal

SELECT * FROM FAILEDRPC select @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Yes SQL Server , I am trying to get one report instead of 35 seperate

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      database_name = DB_NAME(5)
    , log_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'LOG' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , row_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'ROWS' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , emp_count = (SELECT count(*) FROM emp)
    , activebadges = (SELECT count(*) FROM BADGE WHERE STATUS=1)
    , eventstotal = (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.EVENTS)
    , failedrpc = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FAILEDRPC)
FROM sys.master_files WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE database_id =(5) 
GROUP BY database_id
```